# PHP inserting to sql with for loop

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

Trying to insert data to sql when looping,
The variables
$roomPrice = $_POST['roompricepromo'];
$roomNamePromo = $_POST['roomnamepromo'];
Are arrays, that sent by html form ,
the other varialbes are not arrays.

Somehow, **only one row is inserting to the database**, after submiting the form.
also tried normal query(not bind_param) , it doesn't work.
also tried multi_query - doesn't work , multi_query throw a sql syntax error..
I "echo'ed" the data passed by html and the data is fine, nothing missing.

Thanks In Advance.

```
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xxxxx', 'serviceproducts');
    
    if (!$con) {
        "Error:" . $con->mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $roomName = $_POST['rooms'];
    $promotionName = $_POST['promotionname'];
    $roomPrice = $_POST['roompricepromo'];
    $roomNamePromo = $_POST['roomnamepromo'];
    $hotelName = $_POST['hotels'];



    $priceSql = "insert into promotions (promotionname, roomtype, hotelname, price) values (?,?,?,?)";
    $priceStatement = $con->prepare($priceSql);

    for($i = 0; $i<count($roomNamePromo); $i++) {
        echo $roomNamePromo[$i];
        echo $roomPrice[$i];

        $priceStatement-> bind_param("sssi", $promotionName, $roomNamePromo[$i], $hotelName, $roomPrice[$i]);
        $priceStatement->execute(); 

    }
```

Comment: I didnt try, im coding with notepad++

Comment: can you give us html ? and try  var_dump($roomNamePromo) give us the result

Comment: Guys Thanks for help , After screaming 48hr trying to solve this wierd problem, i find out that the problem caused becuse primary key inside table, i created new table without primary key and now it works like a magic, but the problem now that in this table i cannot edit the rows manually.  any idea?

Comment: make your primary key auto incremet

Comment: Worked, Thank you very much, I hope this post will be helpful for another who stuck in my problem